# Inno Setup - Install destination in user specific folder

Tags: compilation, installation, inno-setup, user-profile

I try to compilate a bunch of files with Inno Setup 5 and want the install destination to vary depending on which user is logged in.

When user1 is logged in and runs the setup file, the path should be C:\Users\user1 and when user2 is logged in it should be C:\Users\user2.

I use this code and it kinda works, only the path is "stuck" on my user who compilated the setup file.

```
[Setup]
DefaultDirName={%USERAPPDATA}\target_folder
```

...generates C:\Users\user1\target_folder.

I feel like there is some elegant solution to this but I can't for the life of me find it on the internet... Please help me.

Comment: The issue may be that when you run setup for the second time it reads the path from registry first and it suggests that folder if already exists. Please check [`usepreviousappdir` parameter](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_usepreviousappdir)  and set it to `no`

Comment: Sorry, that didn't do anything to this matter.

Comment: `[Setup] 
DefaultDirName={userappdata}\target_folder
UsePreviousAppDir=False`

Comment: But still before the test you should uninstall all previous Application instances (or delete registry entries from Uninstall section)